# Can anyone identify this weed?

Tags: identification, weeds

[image]

It is growing in bare areas of a poorly draining lawn.

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Pennsylvania, Unites States. The opposite scalloped leaves are the true leaves, and the pointier leaves are only on the flowering top. Didn't realize the scalloped leaves were even the same plant when i first saw it.

Comment: Actually I think I found it: some type of speedwell. https://courses.missouristate.edu/pbtrewatha/Corn_Speedwell6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Another answer correctly identified it as speedwell, it is most prevalent in thin turf areas or gardens. Some good news is it reproduces and spreads only by seed. So depending on how much you have hand weeding is an option, it must be dealt with early in the season though before it flowers and goes to seed. The seed can lay dormant through the winter then sprout again come spring.
Upper and lower leaves differ in appearance--a common characteristic of Veronica Spp.